# startimage for swf video

Tags: html, image, flash, flashvars

Hi I am trying to show startimage before my swf video starts playing, I am using flashVars to do this but for some reasons its not working, below is my code:

```
<object id="M97012085" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  width="1440"  height="900"  style="overflow: auto; align:middle;" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0">
  <param name="movie" value="path_to_swf" />
  <param name="loop" value="false" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="play" value="true" />
   <param name="flashVars" value="image=path_to_png" />

<embed bgcolor="#ffffff" align="middle" name="M97012085" loop="false"  src="path_to_swf"  width="1440"  height="900" flashVars="image=path_to_png" style="overflow: auto; align:middle;"  play="true"  wmode="transparent" quality="high"  allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
 </object>
```

Could you please point out what I am doing wrong ? Is it possible to have a image which user can click to start the video ? Thanks

Comment: you're missing a closing quote after the name,  by the way. name="M97012085" loop="false"

Answer (score 2):

Ravi, please use a swfobject to embed your flash files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars   = { 'image' : 'path-to.png' };
        var params      = { 'allowFullScreen' : 'true', 'wmode' : 'window' }; 
        var attributes  = { };
        swfobject.embedSWF( 'index.swf, 'flashIndex', '100%', '100%', '10.1.0', 'swf/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes );
    </script>
```

More info: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Then if you are using AS3.
before you initialize the video player, load image which was parsed to you by flashvars:

```
imageLoader = new Loader ();
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, placeImageOnStage )
imageLoader.load ( new URLRequest ( loaderinfo.parameters.image ) ); // the flashvar parameter
```

after it is beeing loaded initialize your video.

```
function placeImageOnStage ( e : Event ) : void
{
    addChild ( imageLoader.content ) // add your image to stage
    enableVideoControls ();
    prepearVideo ();
    // or something else
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to modify the original video or player, all I have a swf file and I need to show an image before playing. Will any javascript trick will work here?

Comment: The javascript will do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What is the flash player you are using? Are you certain that startimage is a parameter that your specific player uses?

Answer (score 0):

if your video is or can be an FLV file have a look at [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/setup/index.html). Specifically [this page](http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/splash-image.html) with a splash image example.